# cannot create WCF client

Tags: c#, wcf, service, client, app-config

i have WCF service this is my app.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="PassAccessSystem.DBService.DBHostService">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="PassAccessSystem.DBService.IDBHostService">
                    <identity>
                        <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/PassAccessSystem/DBHostService/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

but now when i want to create WCF client , in ADD SERVICE REFERANCE window i cant find my service???
what is wrong in my app.config?? or problem is other?`

```
An error occured while attempting to find services
```

or

```
cannot download metadata
```

Comment: thhis is not web application ,, what web service i can adD?

Comment: is this right app.config?

Answer (score 1):

Need more information. If this is the client side app.config then you need to add  under system.serviceModel/client.  You can't use the server side settings in your app.config.

As you said you are using Add Service Reference then i'd expect you to have submitted the result of that, which is not what i'm seeing in your included config file.

If you are self hosting the wcf service in your own code then i tend to run the host not in debug mode - then add service reference since now the host is running.

Indeed if you are hosting it yourself and using it from a rich client as well then you can skip all that configuration goodbye entirely and use the interfaces directly on the ChannelFactory - but that's a different story...

Comment: this is service side .config file, i try to add referance and when service running in debug and not deb modes, in add service window cant find the service,

Comment: what url you use to find service

Comment: http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/PassAccessSystem/DBHostService/
or
http://10.53.53.11:8733/DBHostService/

Answer (score 1):

You should first verify that you service is not having any issue and it's up and running. In case if service is also in WCF then you can simply browse the service by typing the complete address in browser and you should able to see the service page. Once you can browse you can create client/proxy either by using add reference or svcutil command.

Comment: i show what i do
i have create a Programm, with one Forms project, eiher, add WCF Service, (class, interface) but now when i run programm in task manager i cant find my service, i dont now what problem